# Which one is faster on android? loading images from resource folder or - blobs from sqlite?

Tags: android, image, sqlite

I have 100 images and want to store them on the device. If I had to load them all at once, which one would be faster: loading images from the resource folder or from sqlite as blobs? Why?

Also, I'm using android studio with java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO, the two approaches are not replacements for one another. Beyond that, the details will vary by Android version (which drives the SQLite version), how you are planning on loading them (e.g., downsampling to fit an `ImageView` size), etc.

Comment: Newest SQLite version. Not downsampling, just loading and displaying.

Comment: "Newest SQLite version" -- unless you are using an external SQLite distribution (e.g., SQLCipher for Android), you do not control the SQLite version. I suggest that you write your own benchmark and test it on various bits of hardware, so you know the performance difference with your images, your loading-and-displaying logic, etc. Note that you have limited heap space; I hope that your 100 images each are fairly low-resolution.

Comment: They are around 600x300, so I'm guessing we can say without measuring benchmarks that loading from the resources folder would be faster than from the database.
Also, the exact SQLite version is 3.16.2

Comment: "They are around 600x300" -- that will take ~70MB of heap space, which you may not have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading 100 images at once might blow out your mobile device's memory.
But if you want to know how to get to that crash faster: it depends.
The SQLite authors already did an experiment:
[Internal Versus External BLOBs in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html) :

> For BLOBs smaller than 100KB, reads are faster when the BLOBs are stored directly in the database file. For BLOBs larger than 100KB, reads from a separate file are faster.
>
> Of course, your mileage may vary depending on hardware, filesystem, and operating system. Double-check these figures on target hardware before committing to a particular design.

Comment: I was looking exactly for this, but I couldn't find it on their site. Thanks!